# Exporting blender objects with textures to unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

I'm new to blender and trying to export 3d objects to unity 3d with textures.
Let's say we create a cube and added a texture (using UV mapping) and save
as a .blend file.then drag and drop into the unity3d but textures not showing in the object.
I tried exporting the object as .fbx but it's not working.

Should I import textures into the unity and add them into 3d objects manually?

Comment: Did you copy the image files as well?

Comment: do you mean into unity3d?

Comment: You drag the .blend file at a location under _Assets_. If it contains references to images, Unity cannot find them outside of Assets. So these images need to be under Assets as well. You can test it by double clicking the .blend file in the project view.

Comment: ok that means I should copy textures into unity3d manually.but my question is.. is their a way to add textures attached objects? without coping textures separately?

Comment: In the Texture Prperties Blender you can specify _save an image packed in the .blend file_ but I never got this to work with Unity. On the other hand importing textures separately may be better because you can optimisise and fine tune the import settings.

Answer (score 1):

Unity doesn't support Blender's packed images, though there is a [feature request](https://feedback.unity3d.com/suggestions/the-ability-to-load-materials-an) for this.

Comment: Is this still true - over 5 years later?

Answer (score -1):

According to the [docs](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-ImportObjectBlender.html) all you have to do is save your .blend file in your assets folder. When you switch back to Unity the object will already be in your assets. Ensure that you are using a current version of blender about 2.60.

On the [Unity Answers site](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/124817/why-is-my-imported-fbx-file-not-showing-textures.html) I found that you need to add the textures through Unity. FBX import does not import the textures. Add the texture into Unity and assign it to the object.